# How to JqGrid textbox Value on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I create the JQGrid Row with Textboxes and one button.

Now I need the **Textbox value which is enter by user when click the Save Button**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#tableId').on('click', '#saveLinkId', function(e){
    var last = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();

    console.log(last); // outputs like [88, xxx, ....n]
    return false;
});
```

---

As you have edited your question, so i have to change my answer accordingly. You can try the updated one now.